# Maintaining Complex Unidirectional Relationships in Core Data

Tags: core-data

I am migrating a data model I have in Realm to Core Data (so I can sync with Ensembles). The model is a graph, and in Realm I am managing the integrity of the graph myself with rules about deletions etc in transactions.

I have made an example graph here that aims to describe the crux of my problem.

All objects in my graph are Things. Things have an ordered to-many relationship with their subThings. However, subThings have multiple ways they link back. For example, one DerivedFromThing type has two to-many relationships (their inverses would be in the subThings of another Thing).

[image: Simple Graph example]

So, my graph has a full set of inverse relationships, but not of a fashion that appears to be modelable in Core Data.

Since I already have the code to manage integrity, I am happy to look after all the relationships myself. However, I am getting warnings in my build, so I wanted to double-check I am taking the right approach.

Is there a way to model my many-many relationships in Core Data? If not, are there issues I am going to face ignoring my warnings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend avoiding unidirectional relationships in CoreData: in my experience when you say nothing about the inverse, CD implicitly treats it as "to-one", which is probably not what you want.

Whilst CD can handle many-many relationships, in your case I think you might need to implement your relationships by directly modelling an intermediate entity (or possibly two or more).  For example, you might have an entity named `Association`, with

- an attribute of `associationType` ("parent", "super" or whatever)
- a to-one relationship `associatedTo` to the `Thing` entity (with a to-many inverse)
- a to-one relationship `associatedFrom` to the `DerivedFromThing` entity (also with a to-many inverse)

It's difficult to advise further, since I suspect your true model is more complicated than your example, but the above approach should provide a good degree of flexibility.  See "Modeling a Relationship Based on Its Semantics" in [the Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a very clear explanation of how I could describe the structure completely. I will have a play with that approach. It will make things much more complex, but I don't want to run into unexpected CD implicit assumptions.

Comment: This doesn't quite map out as I had hoped. To make the intermediate Entities work, I would either need to have multiple derived intermediate-entity types (e.g. one that connects between subThings and superThings, one that connects between subThings and parentThings) or I would have to have a generic "superThings" link on Thing to use the associationType proposed here. I will look into both and see what falls out most elegantly.