# Why do I get a crash clearing block-based KVO on self with NSManagedObject?

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, key-value-observing

I have a Core Data model with complex relationships that I have modelled with intermediate 'Connection' objects (further context in this question: [Maintaining Complex Unidirectional Relationships in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121385)).

I don't want the code using the model to be aware of the intermediate connection objects, so I am adding an array property to my main managed objects that exposes the objects connected to (which I want to be observable too).

```
@objc dynamic public internal(set) lazy var hosts: [Point] = {
        let initialHosts = hostConnections.map { $0.superpoint }
        hostsObservation = track(\Matter.hostConnections_!, on: self,
                                 mapping: \HostConnection.superpoint, to: #keyPath(hosts))
        return initialHosts
    }()
```

The code above sets up an observation on the `NSOrderedSet` of connections when the `hosts` array is initialised (using a generic function that can create this pattern on all my connection types). The observations fire as expected.

I invalidate the observation in `willTurnIntoFault()`:

```
override public func willTurnIntoFault() {
        hostsObservation?.invalidate()
        print("hostsObservation \(hostsObservation) invalidated")
        super.willTurnIntoFault()
    }
```

However, I am getting a crash when this object is deallocated in `NSKVODeallocate`.

```
    hostsObservation Optional(<_NSKeyValueObservation: 0x600000ccd920>) invalidated
    2019-11-04 12:02:06.467620+0000 Frame[27900:5614740] [General] An instance 0x60000300bc30 of class FrameGraph.Subject_Subject_ was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x6000002d6ae0> (
    <NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000ccd950: Observer: 0x600000ccd920, Key path: hostConnections_, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x600000c78b10>
...
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3f590e45 __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6a1e63c6 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3f590c77 +[NSException raise:format:] + 193
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff4180f349 NSKVODeallocate + 442
    4   CoreData                            0x00007fff3f060772 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 1154
```

As you can see from the log, I am invalidating the observation just before the crash claiming it is an issue. If I try to set the observation to `nil` 
in `willTurnToFault()` my app crashes at that point.

I am new to Core Data, can anyone help me with what I am missing here? Why is an object that observes it's own property crashing in this way?

EDIT 1:

My track function looks like this:

```
internal func track<P: Point, C: Connection>(_ trackedPath: KeyPath<P, NSOrderedSet>,
                                             on point: P,
                                             mapping connectionPath: KeyPath<C, Point>,
                                             to mappedPoints: String)
    -> NSKeyValueObservation
{
    return point.observe(trackedPath) { [unowned point] data, change in

        // ...

    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I have stripped the crashing code back to this:

```
        public class Matter: Point
        {
            override public func awakeFromFetch() {
                super.awakeFromFetch()
                print("\(hosts)") // Initialise lazy member and set observation
            }

            public override func willTurnIntoFault() {
                super.willTurnIntoFault()
                hostsObservation = nil // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS 
            }

            @objc dynamic public internal(set) lazy var hosts: [Point] = {
                hostsObservation = observe(\.hostConnections_) { [unowned self] data, change in } // Empty observation closure
                return [] 
            }()

            private var hostsObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
        }

// Matter+CoreDataProperties.swift - auto generated
    extension Matter {

        @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Matter> {
            return NSFetchRequest<Matter>(entityName: "Matter")
        }

        @NSManaged public var hostConnections_: NSOrderedSet?

    }
```

I do not understand what happens to `hostsObservation` to make setting it to `nil` in `willTurnToFault()` crash.

I am building for OSX 10.12, using Swift 5 in Xcode 11.1.

EDIT 3:

Reproduced in a new simple project: https://github.com/GilesHammond/KVO-Core-Data-Crash

Comment: What is the class of `Observer: 0x600000ccd920`? Is a `NSTreecontroller` observing?

Comment: @Willeke 0x600000ccd920 is the NSKeyValueObservation, it's owned by the NSManagedObject that is being deallocated. Might the issue be that I am using the Swift closure approach, is that invalid her for some reason?

Comment: Tried your project out on 10.15.1, no crashes on my end.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh Interesting, thank you Lucas. I am on 10.14.4, Xcode 11.1. Did you change the deployment target or leave it on 10.14?

Comment: @Giles I left the deployment target as is and all code. Using Xcode 11.2.

Comment: Thank you for your help @LucasDerraugh. Much appreciated.

Comment: OK, so building in 11.2 I no longer see a crash when setting the observation to nil, but the observation is _not_ cleared and I get the "was deallocated while key value observers were still registered" error again. I don't understand why I cannot clear the observation in willTurnToFault. This is where the documentation says to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key issue seems to be that my Core Data model is in a module.

I have updated the sample project to show the underlying bug here.

I have spoken with Apple support. It seems there is a system bug. Swift does not currently correctly clean up an NSKeyValueObservation on an NSManagedObject when it is in a module.

I have submitted an issue to Apple through Feedback assistant.